# sufficient condition for Lyapunov stability theory

Tags: inequality, optimization, control-theory, nonlinear-system, stability-theory

I am reading a paper:

I am confused about the following (see equations (2) and (3) in the paper): 
http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/7039413/
or
http://groups.csail.mit.edu/robotics-center/public_papers/Majumdar14a.pdf

Consider the following condition:

$$V(x) \leq \rho \Longrightarrow \dot{V}(x) <0$$

The paper says that the sufficient condition for the above is:
$$(x^Tx)(V(x)-\rho)+L(x)\dot{V} \geq 0$$

My question is:

Obviously $x^Tx \geq 0$ and $(V(x)-\rho)\leq 0$. So the first part is less than or equal to $0$.

$\dot{V}<0$. So even though $L(x)<0$, there is no guarantee that the whole function is greater than or equal to $0$. I have no idea why it is the sufficient condition for the first inequality.

Please advise, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You got the logic backwards. The author is saying that Equation (3) is sufficient for Equation (2). In other words, Equation (3) implies (2), not the other way around. Specifically,

$$\Big(\big((x^Tx)(V(x)-\rho)+L(x)\dot{V} \geq 0 \implies -L(x)\dot{V}\le (x^Tx)(V(x)-\rho)\big)\bigwedge -L(x)\ge 0\Big) \implies \big(V(x)-\rho\le 0\implies \dot V\le 0\big).$$

Comment: A few questions to your answer: 1. could you please say something on $-L(x)\geq 0$? Does the first inequality in you answer imply $-L(x) \geq 0$?    2. How to obtain the last result?

Comment: You state $L(x)\le0$ in your question. So it is taken as given. Are you now not assuming its validity?

Comment: No. the reason I will say $L(x)\leq 0$ is because of the observation of (2). If I want to say (3) implies (2), I am not sure if I could assume $L(x)\leq 0$ at first. Moreover, there is no clue of the positiveness or negativeness of $L(x)$ in the first inequality. (But yes if $L(x)\leq 0$, then the last "$\Longrightarrow$" should hold.)

Comment: Then what do you mean by saying "So even though $L(x)<0$"? Saying even though x implies x is taken as true. How does your statement "I will say $L(x)\le0$ is because of the observation of (2)" come about? How would you derive $L(x)\le0$ from Equation (2)?

Comment: I should have said that if ONLY observing "$(\big((x^Tx)(V(x)-\rho)+L(x)\dot{V} \geq 0$", does it imply $L(x)\leq 0$?

Comment: Alright. The answer is of course no. The sign of $L(x)$ is an extraneous condition.